# Architecture design recommendation using OMATPE for specific requests

Tags: netty

I have a typical netty server setup just a bit confused on the "proper" way to implement or rather add an OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor to a pipelinefactory for specific types of requests. For most requests the typical NIO request/response is fine. However for a specific type of request I'd like to use traditional threaded I/O (ala OMATPE) because of the potential for it being a long running request. What I'm doing now is parsing the URI to get the specific type of request. Short requests will be processed normally and requests of type "/long/running/request" I continue to send upstream which passes through an OMATPE which is then passed to an appropriate handler. Is this the way to go? The pipeline looks something like the following:

```
 public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() {
     return Channels.pipeline(
             new HttpMessageEncoder(),
             new HttpMessageDecoder(),
             new shortLivedRequestHandler(),
             executionHandler,
             new longLivedRequestHandler());
 }
```

In the 'shortLivedRequestHandler' those URI's matching a "short-lived" regex will be processed and then sent downstream. If those URI's happend to match a "long-lived" regex then we pass upstream to the "longLivedRequestHandler" which will in theory process in a non-blocking I/O thread and send response downstream when done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try **not** using OMATPE and manually configuring and using your own ThreadPool.

```
// Stored as a private field in your pipeline and passed into the constructor of your handler
Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(16); 

// In your handler
public class MyRequestHandler extends SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler {
    private Executor _executor = null;

    public MyRequestHandler (Executor executor) {
        _executor = executor;
    }

    public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) throws Exception {
        if (requestThatUseThreadPool) {
            _executor.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                   // Do some work in another thread
                   HttpResponse res = new DefaultHttpResponse(HTTP_1_1, OK);
                   res.setContent(ChannelBuffers.copiedBuffer("hello".toString(), UTF_8_CHARSET));
                   ChannelFuture f = ctx.getChannel().write(res);
                }
            });
        } else {
            // Do some work in this thread
            HttpResponse res = new DefaultHttpResponse(HTTP_1_1, OK);
            res.setContent(ChannelBuffers.copiedBuffer("hello".toString(), UTF_8_CHARSET));
            ChannelFuture f = ctx.getChannel().write(res);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The only problem with this, unless I amassing something, is that each of my request handlers needs to return something specific. More than just a 200 is required. Basically the result of the computation in those requests/handlers is returned in some form. Whereas I believe your solution would be assuming a generic response to the client.

Comment: No. You can just write your results into the channel.  I have amended the example above to help you.

Comment: That's interesting ... Is this then essentially doIng the same thing as I listed above only without the netty "overhead"?

Comment: Yes. I believe it is doing a similar thing and have seen several other open source project use similar techniques (e.g. webbit web server).  Note that your requests may not be processed in an ordered manner as   guaranteed by OMATPE.  If you do require ordered request processing, try customizing the Execution Handler as suggested by Norman in the next answer.

Answer (score 1):

An other solution would be to add a custom ExecutionHandler

Something like this:

```
public class AdvancedExecutionHandler extends ExecutionHandler{



    public AdvancedExecutionHandler(Executor executor) {
        super(executor);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleUpstream(ChannelHandlerContext context, ChannelEvent e) throws Exception {
        if (useExecutionHandler(e)) {
            super.handleUpstream(context, e);
        } else {
            // use no thread-pool
            context.sendUpstream(e);
        }
    }

    private boolean useExecutionHandler(ChannelEvent event) {

        // Add some logic here....
        return true;
    }

}
```